# How do I start a new vaadin project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vaadin

**The answer based on the maven archetype approach works. I will update and accept an answer based on using the built in wizard if the IntelliJ wizard/template for Vaadin is ever fixed.***

I managed to create a new project using the maven archetype from a terminal window, and then import that into IntelliJ IDEA, configured the GWT facet, but now when I run it says:

```
"Error running unnamed: No GWT Modules found in 'projectname'"
```

I confess to being a total beginner at Java, IntellIJ, and Vaadin, not to mention GWT.

I also tried creating a new Vaadin projet using the native Vaadin plugin that comes with IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate). I am using Ultimate, but it's a trial.

[image]

**Update::** Originally I could not see any Vaadin projects in the New Project window's list of available project templates.  That's because I was confused by the two-levels-of-new-projects idea in IntelliJ's new project wizard.  Sorted that out now.

**Update2::** I can follow the steps from EITHER of the two answers below and get a project that builds but it doesn't run.  I assume I was right to add the GWT run-target, because before I do that the Run menu is entirely grayed out.  I believe it is grayed out because there are no modules listed in the modules list for the GWT facet.

[image]

I assume that I must create a new Run/Debug configuration which must be one of the following, and GWT made some sense since vaadin is based atop GWT:

[image]

After I add the GWT I still get the same error as I got originally when I started from the maven archetype: No GWT modules. And I have no idea what people are talking about picking from a drop down module...

[image]

**Update3**  Still was unable to get either solution below to work.  Stuck at this screen and unable to get it to show any modules in the "GWT modules to load" combo box which remains grayed out. I believe this is the drop down module that I am supposed to pick, but nothing below tells me how to get it to be un-grayed-out (enabled):

[image]

I eventually managed to (a) add the GWT facet manually, (b) configure it, and (c) now it will run. That leads to a runtime error (the app does not open in the web browser, but it is clear that it's very close to working.)

Comment: In the Run/Debug configuration, you'll have to choose a module from the dropdown `GWT Module to load`.

Comment: I have no idea where that drop-down menu is that you speak of.

Comment: When you choose GWT Configurarion you can also choose the GWT module to load.

Comment: I somehow did not have a GWT facet ADDED let alone configured. That was the hitch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I did this.

First create the Vaadin project using the maven artefact.

```
C:\dev> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=7.0.4 -Dpackaging=war
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] Archetype repository missing. Using the one from [com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application:7.0.4] found in catalog remote
Define value for property 'groupId': : maba
Define value for property 'artifactId': : vaadin-app
Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
Define value for property 'package':  maba: :
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: maba
artifactId: vaadin-app
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: maba
 Y: :
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: vaadin-archetype-application:7.0.4
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: maba
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: vaadin-app
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: maba
[INFO] Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: maba
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: maba
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: maba
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: vaadin-app
[INFO] project created from Archetype in dir: C:\dev\vaadin-app
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 28.122s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 19 08:05:49 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\dev>
```

Then step into the newly created directory and run `mvn install` just to get all dependencies and have a fresh start.

```
c:\dev\vaadin-app> mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
    ...
    ------ LOTS OF STUFF GOING ON ------
    ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:30.373s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 19 08:13:07 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/296M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now open the project by pointing to the newly created `pom.xml`.

[image]

Everything looks fine. Choose to configure the GWT framework in the green box in the upper right corner.

[image]

Now choose the `Edit Configurations...` drop-down.

[image]

Choose the `GWT Configuration`.

[image]

Give it a name and choose the `Module` from the drop-down.

[image]

Now you will have the option to choose `GWT Module to load` with two options at the moment.

[image]

I choose to run the application. In this case it will give you an error.

[image]

This seems to be [a known error](http://vaadin-support.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/VS-17) at the moment. You'll have to add the `vaadin-client-compiler.jar` to classpath manually.

Press the `Project Structure` button in the toolbar.

[image]

Select `Dependencies` tab for the `vaadin-app` and choose to add `Jars or directories...`.

[image]

Navigate to your local maven repository and find the `vaadin-client-compiler-<version>.jar`.

On Mac OS and Linux/Unix, this will found at:
             `~/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-client-compiler/7.0.4/...`

[image]

Press `Ok` and `Ok` again in the `Project Structure` window.

Now once again run the application. No more errors.

[image]

---

Now, I'm not a Vaadin expert so from here you're on your own.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks. This is very detailed.   Curious if you tried to get it working using the Vaadin new-project-wizard as it seems to me that the vaadin new project wizard leaves things CONSIDERABLY more initially broken than starting from the archetype as you have done.

Comment: @WarrenP There is obviously some problems with the plugin and vaadin 7 as you can see in this [IntelliJ Plugins site](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pluginId=6727). As I said I am certainly not a Vaadin expert and I was more curious about how to set it up using maven and IntelliJ.

Comment: I believe it's running, but I get this warning from DevMode: "[WARN] No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl"

Answer (score 2):

Using the Vaadin Plugin:

New Project, Select Java Module - enter project name and location then click next.

Select "Web Application" and "Vaadin Application", check "Create Sample vaad application" and enter a class name. Select a vaadin version.

Click finish.

Note that the generated example application will not compile (!) as I think it was from a beta version of Vaadin 7.

```
/* As Generated */
public class MySampleVaadinApplication extends UI {
  @Override
  public void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    Label label = new Label("Hello Vaadin user");
    addComponent(label);
 }
}
```

This is what it *should* look like

```
/* As it needs to be */
public class MySampleVaadinApplication extends UI {
  @Override
  public void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    Label label = new Label("Hello Vaadin user");
    setContent(label);
 }
}
```

Note that the Vaadin Plugin for intellij is not created or maintained by the Vaadin dev team, but by other(s) so it hasn't been kept up to date. It is absolutely possible to develop Vaadin applications in IntelliJ without it - we do.

> > I confess to being a total beginner at Java, IntellIJ, and Vaadin, not to mention GWT.

Good Luck - you've got a lot of stuff to get your head around!

[image: Select Java Module]
[image: Select "Web Application" and "Vaadin Application"]

Comment: I installed the plugin but I have no Web Application node, nor any sub-notes (WebServices or Vaadin Application) showing in my New Project window. I suspect that something has gone wrong with the plugin registration.  I might just try re-downloading and reinstalling intelliJ again.... I did not select Vaadin in the initial choice, and adding it later appears to leave IntelliJ's vaadin plugin not properly installed.

Comment: Which "edition" of IntelliJ are you using? I suspect that the Web Application "Facet" requires the Ultimate (i.e. not Community edition). Oh, and the Vaadin plugin reqires the Web Application stuff.

Comment: Enable disabled plug-ins in `Settings` | `Plugins`.

Comment: Stuck right back where I was with the Maven Archetype: No GWT Module.

Comment: I've not used the Maven Archetype: - sorry, can't offer any more advice.

Comment: AH: I've seen you've updated the questions. Right: So, you've created a Vaadin Application! Hurrah! That's progress. Now, you need to run it. You *don't* want to run it via anythin to do with GWT; you need to create and run a Web Server such as Tomcat or Jetty. There should be quite a few articles out there about how to run Web Applications in IntelliJ - http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_for_Tomcat_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_12 : Here's one

Comment: To break this down a little : The Vaadin Plugin has created and configured a Vaadin Application in the source; You now need to deploy it and run it. A Vaaadin application is just  like any java webapplication, therefore you just need to find out how to run and deploy webapps in IntelliJ Idea. Sorry if this all seems complex - but, as I said in the beginning, there's a lot to learn here!

Comment: I accepted the other answer but I'm concerned you might be right. For while I can configure a GWT facet, and run it, It doesn't launch my browser, just the "Development Mode" task and then, no browser. No manual attempts to open any `localhost:####` url work either.

Comment: (I know I'm right ;-) Unless you are developing GWT Widgets, you really don't need to do anything with GWT & Vaadin inside - or indeed outside - of IntelliJ...)